# I am looking for Words that are all upper case and has white space

Tags: java, regex

If consecutive uppercase words are in a document "I AM ALL UPPERCASE" what I return is four seperate upper case words.  What I would need is to return the whole uppercase "I AM ALL UPPERCASE". How do i do this?

```
String ucParensRegEx = "\([A-Z]+\)";
if (we.getParagraphText() != null) {
    String[] dataArray = we.getParagraphText();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        String data = dataArray[i].toString();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        while (m.find()) {
            if (!sequences.contains(data.substring(m.start(), m.end())) && !data.equals("ARABIC") && !data.equals("ALATEC") && !data.equals("HYPERLINK")) {
                sequences.add(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
                System.out.println(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
                Acronym acc = new Acronym(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()), data, false);
                accronymList.add(acc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"\\b([A-Z][A-Z ]+[A-Z])\\b"` instead of the expression you have.

This should match any sequence of A-Z, or spaces, as long as they are between an upper case letter and a word boundary on both sides - this should hopefully cover the full sequence of upper case words, unless you've got some requirements about allowing numbers in there.

Comment: Thanks to whoever did the down-vote with no comment as to why... Very constructive.

Comment: This would match spaces as well between lowercase words. Check it out [here](http://regex.powertoy.org/?pat=%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%20%5D+%29%5Cb&syn=javaSyntax&anim=0&rep=&in=Hello%20there%20I%20AM%20ALL%20UPPERCASE%20and%20NONE%20of%20me%20is%20LOWERCASE.%20True%3F%20ISN%27T%20IT%20Not%21%0ADoes%20JOHN%27S%20TEXT%20ALSO%20appear%20AS%20LOWERCASE%20or%20is%20it%20MORE%20mixed.%0AThis%20is%20WORTH%20DESCRIBING%21%20Isn%27t%20IT%3F%0A)

Comment: The other upvoted answer by @Pshemo does not match the spaces between lowercased words. It matches only the spaces between the uppercased words which is what the OP needs. Though not explicitly stated in the question, it is an implied requirement.

Comment: Right. I see what you mean now, I must have misread your statement. If we're only getting spaces between upper case words then none of the answers are quite there yet as they all match trailing spaces. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
String data="Some SENTENCE WITHOUT MEANING AnD OTHER PART OF that SenTENCE.";
String regex = "(\\b[A-Z]+\\b\\s*)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find()) 
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output:

```
SENTENCE WITHOUT MEANING 
OTHER PART OF
```

Comment: I think that is it.  I appreciate it Pshemo.  Awesome.

Comment: @MarkBasler - If this is the answer that helped you best, shouldn't you accept this as the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
((?:\b[A-Z']+\b\s*)+)
```

Please note that you may need the apostrophe in the regex character class as it can occur inside the UPPERCASE word like it does in `ISN'T`.

Java code:

```
  String sourcestring = "Hello there I AM ALL UPPERCASE and NONE of me is LOWERCASE. True? ISN'T IT Not!";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("((?:\\b[A-Z']+\\b\\s*)+)");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
```

This matches:

```
I AM ALL UPPERCASE 
NONE 
LOWERCASE
ISN'T IT
```

You can play with this at [RegexPowertoy](http://regex.powertoy.org/?pat=%28%28%3F%3A%5Cb%5BA-Z%27%5D+%5Cb%5Cs%2a%29+%29&syn=javaSyntax&anim=0&rep=&in=Hello%20there%20I%20AM%20ALL%20UPPERCASE%20and%20NONE%20of%20me%20is%20LOWERCASE.%20True%3F%20ISN%27T%20IT%20Not%21%0ADoes%20JOHN%27S%20TEXT%20ALSO%20appear%20AS%20LOWERCASE%20or%20is%20it%20MORE%20mixed.%0AThis%20is%20WORTH%20DESCRIBING%21%20Isn%27t%20IT%3F%0A)

---

**Update:**

To match acronyms with periods like `U.S.` and avoid single letter acronyms `P.`, you can modify the regex to this:

```
((?:[A-Z]\.){2,}|(?:\b[A-Z][A-Z']*\b[?!]?\s*)+)
```

and play with it [here](http://regex.powertoy.org/?pat=%28%28%3F%3A%5Cb%5BA-Z%27.%5D+%5Cb%5C.%3F%5Cs%2a%29+%29&syn=javaSyntax&anim=0&rep=&in=Hello%20there%20I%20AM%20ALL%20UPPERCASE%20and%20NONE%20of%20me%20is%20LOWERCASE.%20True%3F%20ISN%27T%20IT%20Not%21%0ADoes%20JOHN%27S%20TEXT%20ALSO%20appear%20AS%20LOWERCASE%20or%20is%20it%20MORE%20mixed.%0AThis%20is%20WORTH%20DESCRIBING%21%20Isn%27t%20IT%3F%20How%20about%20U.S.%20currency%3F%0A)
and code can be checked [here](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=4dbb517e)

Comment: So another question what if I need to find uppercase letters that have periods between each letter.  For Example U.S.

Comment: The period at the end of a word always lies beyond the closing word boundary. Hence you should try this: `((?:\b[A-Z'.]+\b\.?\s*)+)` as shown [here](http://regex.powertoy.org/?pat=%28%28%3F%3A%5Cb%5BA-Z%27.%5D+%5Cb%5C.%3F%5Cs*%29+%29&syn=javaSyntax&anim=0&rep=&in=Hello%20there%20I%20AM%20ALL%20UPPERCASE%20and%20NONE%20of%20me%20is%20LOWERCASE.%20True%3F%20ISN%27T%20IT%20Not%21%0ADoes%20JOHN%27S%20TEXT%20ALSO%20appear%20AS%20LOWERCASE%20or%20is%20it%20MORE%20mixed.%0AThis%20is%20WORTH%20DESCRIBING%21%20Isn%27t%20IT%3F%20How%20about%20U.S.%20currency%3F%0A)

Comment: That isn't doing it.  That is also returning One letter with a period. I need a minimum of two or more characters...with periods.

Comment: This may get ugly: `((?:[A-Z]\.){2,}|(?:\b[A-Z][A-Z']*\b[?!]?\s*)+)`